# Numpy 配列の要素を配列に置換する方法

Tags: python, numpy

`np.array` の要素 (数字) を `np.array` に置換する方法が思いつかず，悩んでいます。
例えば以下のような例です。

実行前

```
img = np.array([
  [0, 1, 2], 
  [2, 1, 1],
])
```

この`img[h, w]`の値に対し，例えば値が

```
img[h, w] == 0 のとき np.array([255, 0, 0])  
img[h, w] == 1 のとき np.array([125, 125, 0])
img[h, w] == 2 のとき np.array([0, 125, 125])
```

に置換したいと考えています。つまり，上のimgに対しては

実行後

```
img = np.array([ 
  [[255, 0, 0], [125, 125, 0], [0, 125, 125]],
  [[0, 125, 125], [125, 125, 0], [125, 125, 0]],
])
```

に置換したいです。
最初`np.where`が使えるかと思いましたが，`np.where(conditions, x, y)`の`x, y`は数字でなければならず，配列はNGのようです。
効率的な方法をよろしくお願いします。

Comment: 効率的であるのかどうかは不明ですが、次元が足りないので、`img = img[:, :, np.newaxis]` として、`img = np.where(img == 0, np.array([255, 0, 0]), img)` とするなどはどうでしょうか(1, 2 の場合も同様に処理)。

Comment: 解決しました，ありがとうございます。

Comment: 解決してよかったです。自己回答ができるので回答の記入をご検討ください。

Comment: @metropolis さん、提案レベルでもぜひ回答にお願いします。

Answer (score 1):

numpyの置換にはFancy Indexingを使うのが効率的です。
参考　Python Data Science Handbook [Fancy Indexing](https://jakevdp.github.io/PythonDataScienceHandbook/02.07-fancy-indexing.html)

```
import numpy as np

img = np.array([
    [0, 1, 2], 
    [2, 1, 1],
])    
ind = np.array([np.array([255, 0, 0]), np.array([125, 125, 0]), np.array([0, 125, 125])])
ind[img]
```